# Как лучше организовать базу данных для андроид приложения

Tags: php, android, mysql, база-данных, firebase

Какую базу данных лучше использовать для GPS Trackerа. Хранить данные о местонахождении и обмениваться ими между зарегистрированными пользователями. Что лучше использовать Firebase или PHP+MySql или может вообще что-то другое ?

Comment: Андроид и PHP? Обычно там MySQL. А если не нужно будет по ним искать, то пишите в файл

Comment: @МаксимВласов ну если только API на PHP+MySQL написан, а обычно там вообще sqlite. Файл? между пользователями?

Comment: Если не хотите особо париться, то лучше Firebase http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/. А если трудности для Вас не проблема и хочется получить огромный мешок опыта, то лучше PHP+MySQL+SQlite http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: @iFr0z, конечно SQLite. Мыли были о другом. А на счет файлов: имеет место быть. В зависимости он потребностей. Проще прочитать файл, чем открывать соединение с БД. Это если на стороне клиента. Ведь БД по сути и есть файл.

Comment: @iFr0z, Спасибо. Я понял так - Клиент андроид работает с SQlite и по средствам json запросов общается с PHP+MySQL сервером.

Comment: @dhNkolas именно:) рад был помочь)